# How to send TRX to a smart contract function in tronlink web

Tags: solidity, tron, trx, tronlink

How can I send tron to a smart contract function in tronlink web.
I am trying the below method, but not working.

```
var contract = await tronweb.contract().at('{{env('CONTRACT_ADDRESS')}}')
await contract.Invest({{session('member_id')}}).address.send(amount);
```

it's calling the smart contract function but not sending tron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

callValue - Amount of SUN transferred to the contract with this transaction.
(1TRX = 1,000,000 SUN)

```
await contract.Invest({{session('member_id')}}).send({callValue: amount})
```

You can check tronweb [documentation](https://developers.tron.network/reference#tronwebcontractnew) for send () parameters.